# How to store 14.5 trillion and some change in a C floating point type variable

Tags: c, floating-point, large-data

I'm creating a change counter program for my C++ class. The numbers we are using are in the 10s of trillions and I was wondering if there was an easy way to store that into a floating point type variable then cast that into an integer type. It isn't an integer literal, it's accepted as an input and I expect possible change.

Comment: What would you want to accomplish by casting that number to an integer ?

Comment: Is that 10^12 or 10^18? What sort of precision do you need?  64 bit integer maybe?

Comment: You can use e.g. [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) to get the max and min values a type can hold.

Comment: It starts as a dollar amount with a precision of 2 and is cast into an integer with an invisible floating point for money calculations.

Comment: @user1892641: 14.5 trillion dollars? :)  Just wire me the money and I'll store it for you, don't worry about it.  Trillion can mean different things in different countries.

Comment: As a general tip, _don't_ use floating point data types for monetary values. The rounding problems will drive you crazy. Make up a fixed-point type instead, or search for an existing fixed-point or money library.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That's why I'm casting it into an integer but I need to store the input into a floating point first because I am explicitly asking for xx.yy input.

Comment: Don't use float. Ask for xx.yy, read it as a string, convert the string into integers.

Comment: @user1892641 Why is this range in the trillions? Could you please explain that requirement further as this leads to serious problems in "off the shelf" representation.

Comment: Well I'm calculating how much of the GDP we spend on gas in the U.S. and the GDP is 14.5 trillion for the year 2010 (which I'm using as reference) but which is only one of the numbers I'm using to test this program.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use floats.  Keep it as an integer and use 64-bit longs.  Use "long long" or "int64_t" as the type for storing these integers. The latter can be used by `#include <stdint.h>`

```
int main()
{
    long long x = 1450000000000LL;
    printf("x == %lld\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It needs to be a floating point type because it's asking specifically for an 14.5^10*9.yy.

Comment: @user1892641 14.5 trillions is an integer and so is (14.5 trillions * 100) + yy. Count cents, not dollars.

Comment: Can I just do scanf("%d", (&amount_due *100));?

Comment: Oh sorry, 14.5 is not an integer literal. It's accepted as an input from scanf.

Comment: @user1892641 Where is the problem with that? I'd recommend you read the user input and parse it yourself to identify the correct multiplier. The problem with float is the fact that you are a victim of the accuracy problems introduced by the representation of floating points.

Comment: +1 on what junix just said.  It's usually not a good idea to "read an integer" from text input. Rather, read a string, and then do your own conversion to an integer. You can use atoll() to convert between string to int64.

Comment: long long or int64_t can only hold up to 9.22*10^18, but it is signed. If negative numbers aren't needed, consider using `unsigned long long` or `uint64_t` that can hold up to 18.44*10^18.

Comment: if 64 bit still isn't enough then gcc already has `__int128` that is ready for use

Answer (score 0):

Uhm. No :D

You can however use matrices and write functions for the mathematical operations you need to use. If you're doing a lot or arithmetic with very large numbers, have a look at http://gmplib.org/

Comment: That is way more complicated than I'm looking for. I just was wondering if there was a simple way, but I guess not. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, is it tens of trillions or just 14.5 trillion? That does make quite a difference, because otherwise you can just use a 64bit int.

Comment: Well, one of the numbers is 14.5 trillion. The second number I don't know yet, expected to be several trillion at least.

Answer (score 0):

If you use floating point math to represent your change counter you'll get in serious troubles. Why? - You are a victim of accuracy problems that lead to problems representing values differing in the 1s, 10s and 100s and so on up to (IIRC) 10^6 of the values. (assuming you are referring to 10^12 version of the term 'trillion'. See H. Schmidt's [IEEE 754 Converter page](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) and the [Wikipedia article about this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)if you want deeper insight into this)

So if you need a precision that goes higher than a several million (and I assume you do), you'll really get in hot water if you use such a beast like floating points. You really need something like the ([multiple precision library from GNU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multi-Precision_Library) in order to be able to calculate the numbers. Of course you are free to implement the same functionality yourself.

In your case mabye a 64-bit integer could do it. (Note that long long is not always 64 bit and nonstandard for C89) Just parse the user input yourself by doing something like this (untested, just to illustrate the idea):

```
const char input[] = "14.5"
uint64_t result = 0;
uint64_t multiplier = 1000000000000;
unsigned int i = 0;

/* First convert the integer part of the number of your input value.
   Could also be done by a library function like strtol or something 
   like that */
while ((input[i] != '.')
       && (input[i] != '\0'))
{
    /* shift the current value by 1 decimal magnitude and add the new 10^0 */
    result = (result * 10) + (input[i] - '0'); 
    i++;
}

/* Skip the decimal point */
if (input[i] == '.') 
{
    i++;
}

/* Add the sub trillions */
while (input[i] != '\0') 
{
    /* shift the current value by 1 decimal magnitude and add the new 10^0 */
    result = (result * 10) + (input[i] - '0'); 
    multiplier /= 10;  // as this is just another fraction we have added, 
                       // we reduce the multiplier...
    i++:
}

result = result * multiplier;
```

Of course there are a several exceptions that need to be handled seperatly like overflows of the result or handling non numeric characters properly but as I noted above, the code is only to illustrate the idea.

P.S: In case of signed integers you have to handle the negative sign too of course.

Comment: GMP has a nasty habit of falling apart on out-of-memory conditions, it just exits the program completely, which I consider unforgivable for a general purpose library - I wouldn't use it for serious work unless you're willing to keep an eye out for it.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. I agree this is really bad behaviour. Searching around I found a workaround in combination with C++ (see http://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-discuss/2008-December/003479.html ).